# UWP Microsoft Store App with Code Signing

Tags: uwp, code-signing

I attempting to have a UWP app I created be distributed through the Microsoft Store for another company. The app will be private/hidden on the Store (only that company can download it). Their IT is asking us to Code Sign the app before they will approve it on their network. Everything I have read says that if you go through the Microsoft Store, Microsoft signs the app for you. Is this true? Also, whether it is true or not, can I please get sent some documentation on this? I only see documentation on certificates in regards to Sideloading.

Comment: Hi @Travyguy9, I found you have post the same issue in msdn and our team member has replied your answer  [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/07b7b2c1-8bec-4d56-9dcc-7ad0ccabe624/uwp-store-app-code-signing?forum=windowsstore) please pay a attention to the following update.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks, I will reply to him there

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT The response times are soooo slow on that forum. Is there a faster way to get support for something like this?

Comment: Hi @Travyguy9, Our team member will reply your case, please pay a attention .

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I am paying attention, but maybe it is because of a time zone issue, I get one response per day. You reply at like 3am my time, so I reply when I wake up and then have to wait until it is morning your time. That is slow in my opinion.